# get_template_directory_uri pointing to parent theme not child theme

Tags: functions, child-theme, include

The problem I am having is that the get_template_directory_uri is pointing to the parent theme like `site/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/myGallery/gallery_functions_include.php`

but I want it to point to my child theme which should be `site/wp-content/themes/child-twentythirteen/myGallery/gallery_functions_include.php`

what I am using is `include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/myGallery/gallery_functions_include.php');`

Answer (score 131, accepted):

`get_template_directory_uri()` will always return the URI of the current parent theme.

To get the child theme URI instead, you need to use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`.

You can find these [in the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri), along with a list of other useful functions for getting various theme directory locations.

---

If you prefer to use a constant, then `TEMPLATEPATH` is akin to calling `get_template_directory()` (i.e. the parent theme), and `STYLESHEETPATH` is akin to calling `get_stylesheet_directory()` (i.e. the child theme).

These constants are set by WordPress core in `wp-includes/default-constants.php` and basically look like this:

```
define('TEMPLATEPATH', get_template_directory());
...
define('STYLESHEETPATH', get_stylesheet_directory());
```

If there is no child theme, then both the 'template' *and* 'stylesheet'  functions will return the parent theme location.

Note the difference between these functions and the functions ending in `_uri` - these will return the absolute server path (eg. `/home/example/public_html/wp-content/yourtheme`), whereas the `_uri` functions will return the public address (aka URL) - eg. `http://example.com/wp-content/themes/yourtheme`.

Comment: what about include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/myGallery/gallery_functions_include.php'); this one also goes to the parent directory

Comment: @ElroyFernandes I've added this to my answer. STYLESHEETPATH is the constant you'd want instead

Comment: Thanks for answering the question instead of just saying RTM.  This popped up first in my search results.

Comment: Good answer but bad naming on WordPress's part - it's not just for stylesheets, it's for JS, assets, includes etc.

Comment: @PaulFeakins Don’t get started on naming inconsistencies in WordPress - that’s a long and windy road that leads who-knows-where! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should move your custom templates, those that are not controlled by the active theme, to a child folder.

Keep the theme separate from all customized files this way the theme can be updated without losing your custom work.

```
Your out-of-the-box theme lives here
------------------------------------
\\Site\wp-content\themes\some_theme
```

```
Your child theme lives here
---------------------------
\\Site\wp-content\themes\some_theme-child
```

Your custom styles and templates and all your includes (things like custom javascript, images that are not saved to WP, custom fonts, json data files, and any plugins that you might enqueue) should be moved to child folder OUTSIDE of theme.

```
\themes\some_theme
\themes\some_theme-child\ (all your custom php template files here)
\themes\some_theme-child\images
\themes\some_theme-child\includes 
\themes\some_theme-child\languages
\themes\some_theme-child\json 
\themes\some_theme-child\style
```

For your custom style pages (*not the theme's overridden style.css*) enqueue with
wp_enqueue_style( 'some-css', [get_stylesheet_directory()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory?) . '/style/some.css' , false, '0.0.1', 'all');

Use [get_stylesheet_directory_uri()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri?) with your xhr calls, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

> `include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/path-to/my-file.php');`

with

> `include dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/path-to/my-file.php';`

this should work for most common issues